# data fetching in custom hook always returning initial state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

I'm writing a custom hook to fetch some enums defined in my GraphQL schema for use in form fields. The enum values obviously don't change all that frequently but I wanted to make them available to any form component (or any component). My problem is that no matter how I fire the query, my hook is always returning its initial state. There are several examples of data fetching in custom hooks, and they all follow a pretty similar pattern, e.g., something like this answer: [Fetch data with a custom React hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578865/fetch-data-with-a-custom-react-hook)

I first wrote the hook to use Apollo's `useQuery()`, and I set `data` as a dependency of `useEffect()`.

```
export const useFormFieldEnums = () => {
  const [ enums, setEnums ] = useState( null )

  const ENUMS_QUERY = gql`
    query FormFieldEnums {
      mailingAddressTypes: __type(name: "MailingAddressType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
      emailTypes: __type(name: "EmailType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
      phoneTypes: __type(name: "PhoneType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `

  const { data } = useQuery( ENUMS_QUERY )

  useEffect(() => {
    if ( data ) {
      // result = wrangle data into desired shape
      setEnums( result )
    }
  }, [data])

  return enums
}
```

Done this way, the query is dispatched (I see the request and response in the browser's network tab), but `return enums` isn't executed again after the query resolves with data.

I thought that perhaps the `data` dependency of `useEffect()` was responsible, so I tried using the `query()` method of Apollo Client directly, via the `useApolloClient()` hook, to allow the query to be dispatched asynchronously and have no dependencies for `useEffect()`. Done this way, the query doesn't even appear to be executed. (?)

```
export const useFormFieldEnums = () => {
  const [ enums, setEnums ] = useState( null )
  const client = useApolloClient()

  const ENUMS_QUERY = gql`
    query FormFieldEnums {
      mailingAddressTypes: __type(name: "MailingAddressType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
      emailTypes: __type(name: "EmailType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
      phoneTypes: __type(name: "PhoneType") {
        name
        enumValues {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `

  useEffect(async() => {
    try {
      const { data } = await client.query({ query: ENUMS_QUERY })
      // result = wrangle data into desired shape
      setEnums( result )
    } catch ( error ) {
      console.error( error )
    }
  }, [])

  return enums
}
```

In both cases I'm always getting the initial state of `enums` back from the hook, even though `return enums` should be executed each time the value of `enums` changes. Presumably, `setEnums( result )` is not getting called, but I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `// result = wrangle data into desired shape` is not enough when looking for  errors ... details ... you can always `console.log(data, result)` to check if effect code is run

Comment: That omitted code is simply some `map` calls and object property assignment. It's not really relevant to the issue. What is a problem is that I don't see _any_ `console.log()` statements that I've put inside the `useEffect()` call.